# Как в PHP отделить HTTP-запросы из мобильного приложения PhoneGap от всех остальных?

Tags: php, android, ios, http, phonegap

Имеется мобильное приложение для **iOS** и **Android** созданное при помощи: **Framework7 + PhoneGap**

Мобильное приложение делает HTTP-запросы к сайту, который написан на **PHP**.

**Как на сайте в PHP однозначно идентифицировать HTTP-запрос от мобильного приложения PhoneGap?**

**p.s.:** писать отдельные запросы или добавлять к запросам какую-нибудь GET-переменную не представляется возможным, интерфейсов много как и запросов...

---

Решение вопроса:

Использовать в **config.xml** строку:

```
<preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="Ваше добавочное значение" />
```

ну а далее в PHP на сервере смотреть на наличие этого добавочного значение в **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный способ заключается в том, что бы выставить себе "правильный User Agent". Это можно сделать буквально [в одну строку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624259/change-phonegap-user-agent):

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="MyBaggyApp/1.2.3" />
```

Все, теперь на сервере будет очень легко отличать (а как прочитать User Agent знает даже слабенький джун).

Теперь можно передавать и тип оси (android/iOs), версию приложения (или даже лучше версию протокола).

Comment: Заменил UserAgent-заголовок на своё значение, у меня Framework7 интерфейс теперь масштабируется на весь экран перекрывая верхнюю статусную панель (где батарейка, часы и прочее). Есть ли возможность добавить к оригинальному UserAgent-заголовку своё значение а не полностью его переписывать?

Comment: вместо OverrideUserAgent, я попробовал: AppendUserAgent, а то даже у них в: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/config.html написано: "OverrideUserAgent (string, not set by default): If set, the value will replace the old UserAgent of webview. It is helpful to identify the request from app/browser when requesting remote pages. Use with caution, this may causes compitiable issue with web servers. For most cases, use AppendUserAgent instead."
Безопаснее юзать: AppendUserAgent

Comment: а уж найти то в $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] вхождение нужных мне слов я конечно же смогу ). Спасибо Вам за подсказку!